# How to create a draggable modal in Dash python?

Tags: python-3.x, bootstrap-modal, plotly-dash

I want to create a modal in plotly-Dash python. I can create it with [Modal components of bootstrap Dash](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/modal/). The problems are:

1- I couldn't drag the modal.

2- I couldn't interact with the back of modal.

Is there any way to solve these issues?

Are there another component that i can use it instead of Modal component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create modal just with HTML and CSS in your Dash app by importing the module
`dash_html_components`, the step-by-step code of how the modal will be made can be better explained  [here](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/).